# Вставить изображение в pdf документ c#

Tags: c#, pdf, png, itextsharp

Использую данный код для того, чтобы вставить изображение в pdf документ. На строке `var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream);` возникает ошибка `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."` Подскажите, в чем ошибка.

```
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Stream inputPdfStream = new FileStream("input.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (Stream inputImageStream = new FileStream("some_image.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (Stream outputPdfStream = new FileStream("result.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            var reader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);
            var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream);
            var pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(1);

            Image image = Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream);
            image.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 100);
            pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);
            stamper.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Предоставленной информации недостаточно. Трассировку стека покажите.

Comment: +  $exception {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} System.NullReferenceException
  args {string[0]} string[]
+  inputPdfStream {System.IO.FileStream} System.IO.Stream {System.IO.FileStream}
+  inputImageStream {System.IO.FileStream} System.IO.Stream {System.IO.FileStream}
+  outputPdfStream {System.IO.FileStream} System.IO.Stream {System.IO.FileStream}
+  reader {iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader} iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader
  **stamper** null iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper
+  pdfContentByte null iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte
+  image null iTextSharp.text.Image

Comment: Не так, а прямо в вопросе, его можно редактировать. Полностью надо.